# Postgres inconsistent use of Index vs Seq Scan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having difficulty understanding what I perceive as an inconsistancy in how postgres chooses to use indices.  We have a query based on `NOT IN` against an indexed column that postgres executes sequentially, but when we perform the same query as `IN`, it uses the index.

I've created a simplistic example that I believe demonstrates the issue, notice this first query is sequential

```
CREATE TABLE node
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  vid INTEGER
);
CREATE INDEX x ON node(vid);

INSERT INTO node(vid) VALUES (1),(2);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM node
WHERE NOT vid IN (1);

Seq Scan on node  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=2129 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (vid <> 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Total runtime: 0.025 ms
```

But if we invert the query to `IN`, you'll notice that it now decided to use the index

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM node
WHERE vid IN (2);

Bitmap Heap Scan on node  (cost=4.34..15.01 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (vid = 1)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on x  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=11 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (vid = 1)
Total runtime: 0.039 ms
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? Specifically, is there a way to re-write out `NOT IN` to work with the index (when obviously the result set is not as simplistic as just 1 or 2).

We are using Postgres 9.2 on CentOS 6.6

Comment: What happens if you write:  `WHERE vid NOT IN (1)` ?

Comment: That was a good thought -- but unfortunately -- it made no difference. Somehow `NOT IN` is not just a simple inverse of `IN` from the planners perspective.

Comment: `Somehow NOT IN is not just a simple inverse of IN from the planners perspective` :which is correct, since vid is NULLable.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is going to use an Index when it makes sense. It is likely that the statistics state that your NOT IN has too many tuples to return to make an Index effective.

You can test this by doing the following:

```
set enable_seqscan to false;
explain analyze .... NOT IN
set enable_seqscan to true;
explain analyze .... NOT IN
```

The results will tell you if PostgreSQL is making the correct decision. If it isn't you can make adjustments to the statistics of the column and or the costs (random_page_cost) to get the desired behavior.

Comment: In the example I shared, the table has exactly two rows, one row where vid=1 and where where vid=2. `IN` and `NOT IN` should yield the same decision making, no?

Comment: No because the planner is detecting that there are twice as many NOT IN as IN, in short it is going to be faster to seqscan for those two rows versus going to an index to get a pointer and back to the page in the table to pull the rows.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. The table has two rows. EACH query returns only one row.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I misread. I thought you said there are two NOT IN matching rows and one matching IN rows. In looking at your plans, it appears the planner thinks there are quite a few more rows in that table than is reality. Have you ran a vacuum analyze on the table recently?

Comment: I just ran VACUUM ANALYZE and re-ran the test. The same results -- `NOT IN` is sequential and `IN` uses the index.

Comment: Weird, I am able to reproduce your results. I am tinkering, moment.

Comment: I do not know why it is doing what it is doing. I can tell you that if you perform the same test using id (versus vid) you will (or at least I did) get an index scan for both. In fact an index only scan because it was a primary key. Sorry I wasn't more help.